# I am getting an error when I do rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am getting an error when I do rake db:create. It gives me an error and as far as I know, It didn't work.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _fopen$DARWIN_EXTSN
 Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/libruby.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _fopen$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/libruby.1.dylib
   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ruby install is either the snow leopard default one or you messed with your ruby install. Re-install ruby. (use RVM)

Comment: I know. I deleted the file and so I copied a file from SL to L.